# INSERT with web.py

Tags: insert, web.py, psycopg2

I started a new database named GREEN.db with one TABLE defined as followed:

```
CREATE TABLE articles(
                      "articleID" serial NOT NULL,

                      "articleTitle" character varying(21) NOT NULL,

                      "articleContent" text NOT NULL,

                      "articleAuthor" character varying(7) NOT NULL ,

                      "articleTime" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),

                      CONSTRAINT articles_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("articleID")
                      )
```

And my code was written as followed:

```
db = web.database(dbn='postgres', db='green',user='YOng',password='xxx')

......

i = web.input()
t = time.localtime(time.time())
st = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", t)
datas = list(db.query("""SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY "articleID" DESC"""))
    n = db.insert("articles",
    articleID=len(datas)+1, \
    articleTitle=i.post_title, \
    articleContent=i.post_content, \
    articleAuthor="YOng", \
    articleTime=st)
web.seeother('/')
```

The error threw out saying:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "articleid" of relation "articles"
>   does not exist LINE 1 : INSERT INTO articles (articleTitle,
>   articleAuthor, articleID... ^

I don't know what happened to this code. Does Anyone have any suggestion? Any help appreciated~

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because of the uppercase letters?

the Error is :

```
column "articleid" of relation "articles" does not exist
```

your column name is "articleID"

Comment: Exactly. web.py translates the query as follows: `INSERT INTO articles (articleID, articleTitle, articleContent, articleAuthor, articleTime) VALUES (...)`. According to SQL, column names are treated as case-insensitive, unless you surround them with double quotes: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS